# How get JSON or XML from shared google spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need request json from shared spreadsheet. Example from internet dont work. I try:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheet/KEY/private/full
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/od3/public/basic?alt=json
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/gid3/public/basic?alt=json
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/3/public/basic?alt=json
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/3/KEY/od6/public/basic?alt=json
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/3/KEY/od6/public/basic?alt=json
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/od6/public/basic?alt=json
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/KEY/7/public/values
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/KEY/7/private/values?alt==json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/KEY/7/public/basic?alt==json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/KEY/7/public/basic?alt==json-in-script&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/od6/public/values?alt=json&callback=importGSS
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/od6/public/values?alt=json
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=x
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/KEY/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=
```

Where KEY from https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=KEY#gid=7

Google say "invalid request URI" or "The spreadsheet at this URL could not be found. Make sure that you have the right URL and that the owner of the spreadsheet hasn't deleted it."

Comment: Looks like you are missing the OAuth2 stuff.

Other options: "google-apps-script html service" is maybe the fastest and simplest. The google-drive-api will let you download a file and CSV or HTML or Excel. I suspect you would need to convert the file to JSON/XML but there is lots of code around that will convert.